# Can I use Javascript with Skeleton?

Tags: javascript, css, frameworks, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I can't find an answer. I'm trying to use a framework for the first time, Skeleton (getskeleton.com). I have a Javascript file, which I reference in HTML as usual. But the JS doesn't work. Is there some reason for this? I can't find any documentation about using JS with Skeleton.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. We can't tell you what it is without seeing your code though. Try using the developer tools in your browser to debug it.

Comment: I'm asking generally whether there is a problem using JS in Skeleton or if there is something I'm missing, for example, does Skeleton require JQuery? I'm using JS that works elsewhere so I don't believe it is the problem, hence, the reason, I didn't post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skeleton is just a small boilerplate for modern webpages providing some CSS styles for common UI elements e.g. grids or forms.

At all it has nothing to do with your javascript file and should not affect it since it is build with **pure CSS**.

You might post your code (codepen or something like that). Then we are able to check what's wrong with your javascript.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: Finally, I figured it out. I had put my js file in the wrong folder. No matter how many times I looked at it, I just didn't see what I'd done. So, the answer was not related to JS or Skeleton. Thanks anyway!